# Tell urllib2 to use custom DNS

Tags: python, dns, urllib2, dnspython, urlopen

I'd like to tell `urllib2.urlopen` (or a **custom opener**) to use `127.0.0.1` (or `::1`) to resolve addresses. I wouldn't change my `/etc/resolv.conf`, however.

One possible solution is to use a tool like `dnspython` to query addresses and `httplib` to build a custom url opener. I'd prefer telling `urlopen` to use a custom nameserver though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like name resolution is ultimately handled by `socket.create_connection`.

```
-> urllib2.urlopen
-> httplib.HTTPConnection
-> socket.create_connection
```

Though once the "Host:" header has been set, you can resolve the host and pass on the IP address through down to the opener.

I'd suggest that you subclass `httplib.HTTPConnection`, and wrap the `connect` method to modify `self.host` before passing it to `socket.create_connection`.

Then subclass `HTTPHandler` (and `HTTPSHandler`) to replace the `http_open` method with one that passes your `HTTPConnection` instead of httplib's own to `do_open`.

Like this:

```
import urllib2
import httplib
import socket

def MyResolver(host):
  if host == 'news.bbc.co.uk':
    return '66.102.9.104' # Google IP
  else:
    return host

class MyHTTPConnection(httplib.HTTPConnection):
  def connect(self):
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((MyResolver(self.host),self.port),self.timeout)
class MyHTTPSConnection(httplib.HTTPSConnection):
  def connect(self):
    sock = socket.create_connection((MyResolver(self.host), self.port), self.timeout)
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)

class MyHTTPHandler(urllib2.HTTPHandler):
  def http_open(self,req):
    return self.do_open(MyHTTPConnection,req)

class MyHTTPSHandler(urllib2.HTTPSHandler):
  def https_open(self,req):
    return self.do_open(MyHTTPSConnection,req)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(MyHTTPHandler,MyHTTPSHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

f = urllib2.urlopen('http://news.bbc.co.uk')
data = f.read()
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.HTML(data)

>>> print doc.xpath('//title/text()')
['Google']
```

Obviously there are certificate issues if you use the HTTPS, and you'll need to fill out MyResolver...

Comment: I don't think I'll need HTTPS for now, so this will perfectly suffice! Thank you very much!

Comment: It's also possible to override `HTTPConnection._create_connection`, which is available since Python 2.7.7 and 3.5 due to http://bugs.python.org/issue7776.

Answer (score 23):

Another (dirty) way is monkey-patching `socket.getaddrinfo`.

For example this code adds a (unlimited) cache for dns lookups.

```
import socket
prv_getaddrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo
dns_cache = {}  # or a weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
def new_getaddrinfo(*args):
    try:
        return dns_cache[args]
    except KeyError:
        res = prv_getaddrinfo(*args)
        dns_cache[args] = res
        return res
socket.getaddrinfo = new_getaddrinfo
```

Comment: One advantage of this hack is also intercepts nearly all dns lookups in python, not only via `urlopen`

Comment: this is a better solution if the hosts are scoped in a small number. i have a 10X speed up with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement your own dns lookup client (or using dnspython as you said). The name lookup procedure in glibc is pretty complex to ensure compatibility with other non-dns name systems. There's for example no way to specify a particular DNS server in the glibc library at all.