# Resolve hostname in PHP using different name server

Tags: php, dns, nslookup

How I can resolve hostname to IP address using PHP,
but using different nameserver (eg. [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) or [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/)).

It not seem that `dns_get_record()` or `gethostbyname()` are able to use a different nameserver than one currently set up on the system (in TCP/IP settings or in `/etc/resolv.conf`).

The only way I've found is using PEAR class Net/DNS, but it gives me lots of warnings under PHP 5.4

Comment: Is it an option to run a python script through exec and just read the shell output?  I've seen this same problem solved in urllib2 on SO here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236498/tell-urllib2-to-use-custom-dns/2237040#2237040

Comment: @DeaconDesperado: Why use a python script?  If you can `exec` in PHP, why not just call the unix `host` command?  `exec('host google.com 8.8.8.8')`?

Comment: @Rocket, just suggesting what I was familiar with, hence the comment rather than answer ;)

Comment: good choice, but I want it to be fast. exec() actually forks and uses pipes to redirects the stdin and stdout. This is quite costly operation and in my case will be waste of CPU resources.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [net_dns2](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS2/redirected) (it's also in PEAR).

Comment: looks promising, will give you feedback soon

Comment: require_once 'Net/DNS2.php';

$resolver = new Net_DNS2_Resolver( array('nameservers' => array('8.8.8.8')) );

$resp = $resolver->query("hooktube.com.", 'A');

print_r($resp);

echo $resp->answer[0]->address;

Comment: [https://netdns2.com/documentation/examples/](https://netdns2.com/documentation/examples/)

Answer (score 11):

```
<?
require_once 'Net/DNS2.php';

$resolver = new Net_DNS2_Resolver( array('nameservers' => array('208.67.222.123')) );

$resp = $resolver->query("hooktube.com.", 'A');

print_r($resp);

echo $resp->answer[0]->address;
```

Comment: It is possible if the IP of a visitor to my web. Whether the visitor uses the DNS to Google?

Comment: yes, but you do not need to use dns2 for this. apache /php gives you $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] for this. If unsure - do print_r($_SERVER) or ask question about it.

Comment: Excuse me. To know if the visitor of my web using google public dns?

Answer (score 8):

If you are allowed to run shell scripts from your script, you can use the system's `nslookup` command.

```
$host = 'stackoverflow.com';
$dns = '8.8.8.8';  // Google Public DNS

$ip = `nslookup $host $dns`; // the backticks execute the command in the shell

$ips = array();
if(preg_match_all('/Address: ((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})/', $ip, $match) > 0){
    $ips = $match[1];
}

print_r($ips);
```

Note: use `escapeshellarg` if `$host` and `$dns` are from user input.

Comment: @jcarlosweb: I'm sorry, but I can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Excuse me. To know if the visitor of my web using google public dns?

Comment: There is no way to detect this. Why you need such information anyway?

Comment: I am getting these responses.
Note that for yahoo it says: 'Addresses'

C:\Users\User>nslookup slavi-2016-05-04.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find slavi-2016-05-04.com: Non-existent domain

 
C:\Users\User>nslookup yahoo.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    yahoo.com
Addresses:  2001:4998:58:c02::a9
          2001:4998:c:a06::2:4008
          2001:4998:44:204::a7
          98.138.253.109
          98.139.183.24
          206.190.36.45