# Python - get IP from HTTP request using requests module

Tags: python, python-requests

**The problem**

I need to check if domain from URL is not pointing to a private IP before request and also return IP that was used for HTTP connection.

This is my test script:

```
import ipaddress
import requests
import socket
import sys

from urllib.parse import urlparse


def get_ip(url):
    hostname = socket.gethostbyname(urlparse(url).hostname)
    print('IP: {}'.format(hostname))
    if hostname:
        return ipaddress.IPv4Address(hostname).is_private

def get_req(url):
    private_ip = get_ip(url)
    if not private_ip:
        try:
            with requests.Session() as s:
                s.max_redirects = 5
                r = s.get(url, timeout=5, stream=True)
            return {'url': url, 'staus_code': r.status_code}
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
            return 'ERROR'
    return 'Private IP'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_req(sys.argv[1]))
```

This won't work if domain is resolving to multiply IPs, for instance if website is hosted behind CloudFlare:

```
# python test.py http://example.com
IP: 104.31.65.106
{'staus_code': 200, 'url': 'http://exmaple.com'}
```

A snippet from tcpdump:

```
22:21:51.833221 IP 1.2.3.4.54786 > 104.31.64.106.80: Flags [S], seq 902413592, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 252001723 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:21:51.835313 IP 104.31.64.106.80 > 1.2.3.4.54786: Flags [S.], seq 2314392251, ack 902413593, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
22:21:51.835373 IP 1.2.3.4.54786 > 104.31.64.106.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, length 0
```

The script tested it on `104.31.65.106` but HTTP connection was made on `104.31.64.106`

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492484/how-do-i-get-the-ip-address-from-a-http-request-using-the-requests-library) thread but I won't be consuming the response body so [the connection won't be released](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) and actually my version of requests module doesn't have these attributes.

Is there a way to achive this with `requests` module or do I have to use another library like `urllib` or `urliib3`?

To clarify: I only need to prevent the request if an attempt would be made to connect to a private network address. If there are multiple options and a public address is picked, it's fine.

Comment: Why exactly doesn't `rsp=requests.get(..., stream=True);rsp.raw._connection.sock.getpeername()` work for you?

Comment: OK, so I just tested it and I guess I could close connection in try/except block but it looks like stream works only if server has keep-alive enabled, otherwise connection is closed immediately and I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getpeername'`. I would like to also check IP before request is made.

Comment: Why all the shenanigans with `with requests.Session() as s` then `s = requests.Session()`? That just replaced your configured session, drop the `s = ...` line.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I believe that's what left from testing, I just removed it.

Comment: So if a hostname can resolve to either a public address or a private one, you want to block that request? Or only if the *currently picked IP address* is not a public one?

Comment: Say `foo.com` is registered as being available on `192.168.2.42` and `104.31.64.106`, should the request be blocked even though `requests` was going to use `104.31.64.106`?

Comment: In other words, does the *possibility* of using a non-public address matter here, or only the *actual use* of such an IP address?

Comment: I want to prevent requests to private IPs only so it want hit the web server itselt. I would like to implement this to Django app.

Comment: @HTF: that doesn't answer my question, not really. What should happen when a hostname resolves to multiple IP addresses. Should it a) prevent the request altogether, b) pick one of the non-private IP addresses, or c) only prevent the request if a private IP address is being picked? The fact that this is for a Django app doesn't actually matter.

Comment: `c) only prevent the request if a private IP address is being picked`

Comment: @HTF: but what happens then is that a `OSError: [Errno 65] No route to host` exception is raised, and urllib3 just moves on to the next address in the options. So for *multiple addresses*, this is just fine, `urllib3` just will skip over that address and move on to the next.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you need this. Non-routable IP addresses are automatically skipped; each DNS result is tried in turn until a successful connection is made. Private network addresses are thus *skipped without your intervention*. Besides, including a private-network IP address in public DNS information is huge misconfiguration, and doesn't happen that often. Why is this a problem you need to solve?

Comment: This is just a safety check for corner cases when a user try to submit a URL that is pointing to a private IP, loopback or 0.0.0.0 because in that case request will go to a web server hosting this app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urllib3` will automatically skip unroutable addresses for a given DNS name. This is not something that needs preventing.

What happens internally when creating a connection is this:

- DNS information is requested; if your system supports IPv6 (binding to `::1` succeeds) then that includes IPv6 addresses.
- *In the order that the addresses are listed*, they are tried one by one

  - for each address a suitable socket is configured and
  - The socket is told to connect to the IP address
  - If connecting fails, the next IP address is tried, otherwise the connected socket is returned.

See the [`urllib3.util.connection.create_connection()` function](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/15a1efae8c4af5bf2e08cd33a8b38f9a1312e54f/urllib3/util/connection.py#L32-L85). Private networks are usually not routable and are thus skipped *automatically*.

However, if you are *on* a private network yourself, then it is possible that an attempt is made to connect to that IP address anyway, which can take some time to resolve.

The solution is to [adapt a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609385/python-requests-library-define-specific-dns/22614367#22614367) that lets you resolve the hostname at the point where the socket connection is created; this should let you *skip* private use addresses. Create your own loop over `socket.getaddrinfo()` and raise an exception at that point if a private network address would be attempted:

```
import socket
from ipaddress import ip_address
from urllib3.util import connection


class PrivateNetworkException(Exception):
    pass


_orig_create_connection = connection.create_connection

def patched_create_connection(address, *args, **kwargs):
    """Wrap urllib3's create_connection to resolve the name elsewhere"""
    # resolve hostname to an ip address; use your own
    # resolver here, as otherwise the system resolver will be used.
    family = connection.allowed_gai_family()

    host, port = address
    err = None
    for *_, sa in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
        ip, port = sa
        if ip_address(ip).is_private:
            # Private network address, raise an exception to prevent
            # connecting
            raise PrivateNetworkException(ip)
        try:
            # try to create connection for this one address
            return _orig_create_connection((ip, port), *args, **kwargs)
        except socket.error as err:
            last_err = err
            continue

        if last_err is not None:
            raise last_err

connection.create_connection = patched_create_connection
```

So this code looks up the IP addresses for a host early, then raises a custom exception. Catch that exception:

```
with requests.Session(max_redirects=5) as s:
    try:
        r = s.get(url, timeout=5, stream=True)
        return {'url': url, 'staus_code': r.status_code}
    except PrivateNetworkException:
        return 'Private IP'
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return 'ERROR'
```

Comment: Thanks, any suggestion where I could pass IP that the connection was actually made on to `requests.raw._original_response`?

Comment: @HTF: I'm going to assume you are using Python 3 and therefor other answers you found on SO that apply to Python 2 no longer work. That's because the socket file is a little more complex now. `requests.raw._original_response` is a `http.client.HTTPResponse` instance, `.fp` is the socketfile, which here consists of a buffer wrapping a `SocketIO` object with the actual socket in the `_sock` attribute. So the original socket is available as `requests.raw._original_response.fp.raw._sock`. Call `.getpeername()` on that.