# Requests equiv of curl --resolve

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a curl command that works fine with `--resolve`, but can't figure out the equivalent with [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org).  (If there is one.)

Simplified example:

```
URL: 192:168.1.1
Socket: 9999
User: fred
Password for fred: 123456
Path to resolve:  https://number.street.city:9999/mypath/info
```

Curl command:

```
curl -v -u fred:123456 -k -H "Content-Type: application/json"
     --resolve number.street.city:9999:192.168.1.1 
     https://number.street.city:9999/mypath/info
```

I'm guessing `session.resolve_redirects` has an answer, but I don't know how.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `requests.get(..., allow_redirects=True)`?

Comment: Related: [Python 'requests' library - define specific DNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22609385/846892)

Comment: `--resolve` has nothing to do with redirects; `--resolve` bypasses DNS lookups and tells `curl` to use a specific IP address instead. See the duplicate on how to make requests use a fixed IP address instead of a DNS lookup.