# Replicating "--connect-to" from curl in Python

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate, aiohttp

From the command line, I am able to successfully execute a command as follows:

```
curl --cacert <cacert> --cert <cert> --connect-to ::1.2.3.4: https://some-identity.com:443/endpoint
```

I am doing this so the request ends up going to the `1.2.3.4` address (from the routing perspective), but all of the SSL handshake occurs using the `some-identity.com` address. I have to do this because unfortunately, the SSL certificates in use are being signed using the `some-identity.com` address, but the private IP of the server is `1.2.3.4`.

I am trying to use either `aiohttp` (preferably), or `requests`, but I cannot find the respective utilities to do this.

In `aiohttp`, I see that I can pass in an `SSLContext` (in the `ssl` package) object, but unfortunately, I can't seem to find any property within an `SSLContext` object that can be set dynamically.

For the `requests` library, it doesn't seem to have an option for me to override/change the host as I did using `curl`.

Is there another way to go about this through Python libraries? The last ditch option would be to simply use the `curl` command itself through Python, but that is not preferred.

Comment: portal https://curl.trillworks.com/ can convert `curl` to (more or less correct) `requests`. Maybe it can convert your `curl` too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 'requests' library - define specific DNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609385/python-requests-library-define-specific-dns)