# Implementing the curl --resolve flag in python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have to implement a curl command similar to this `curl -XPOST -u $(<creds) -H "Accept:application/*+xml" --resolve 'xyz.ddns.net:443:12.222.22.222' https://xyz.ddns.net/api/keys` in python.
I have done a lot of research but can not find a way of implementing the **--resolve domain:port:ip** flag using Requests library

Comment: I believe you can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609385/python-requests-library-define-specific-dns

Comment: The `--resolve` flag works slightly differently from the usual DNS override. I believe it only maps a single <host:port> pair to the the IP (as opposed to all ports of that host)