# Equivalent of `curl --connect-to` in Python Requests library with HTTPS working

Tags: python, ssl, curl, https, request

Follow up question to
[Equivalent of `curl --connect-to` in Python Requests library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60666126/equivalent-of-curl-connect-to-in-python-requests-library)

```
curl has an option connect-to

   --connect-to <HOST1:PORT1:HOST2:PORT2>

          For  a  request  to  the  given  HOST:PORT pair, connect to CONNECT-TO-HOST:CONNECT-TO-PORT instead.  This option is suitable to direct requests at a specific
          server, e.g. at a specific cluster node in a cluster of servers.  This option is only used to establish the network connection. It does NOT affect  the  host-
          name/port  that is used for TLS/SSL (e.g. SNI, certificate verification) or for the application protocols.  "host" and "port" may be the empty string, meaning
          "any host/port".  "connect-to-host" and "connect-to-port" may also be the empty string, meaning "use the request's original host/port".

          This option can be used many times to add many connect rules.
What is the equivalent in Python Requests library?
```

Answered with
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61790319/6370776

however that only works for http, the solution only works for https if you run it with `verify=False` i.e.

```
with connect_to('127.0.0.1', 8080):
    res = requests.get('https://service.example.com/', verify=False)
```

Does anyone know how to get it working https?

Meta: why is this a new question and not a comment on the answer?, it's because my rep is too low to allow for commenting.

Comment: *"however that only works for http, the solution only works for https if you run it with verify=False "* - are you sure? From my understanding the solution changes only the target IP address and port, similar to what `--connect-to` with curl does. Of course, the different target server must actually provide a trusted certificate for the URL in question, but this is true also with `--connect-to`.

Comment: The problem is that the SSL lib tries to call the url but it doesn't have the new IP so it returns:



    ... (exceptions)
      File "[CUR_DIR]/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 563, in send
        raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='host-i-try-to-call.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /path/i/call (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)')))