# Python requests get website using custom dns

Tags: python, proxy, dns, python-requests

I need to access a specific server and it just responses to connections with a specific DNS server. So before connecting to that website I need to set my system DNS servers to custom IPs. That's ok, but now I'm working on a python script with a requests module and I want to access that server. How can I set custom DNS IPs to requests session to do GET function with those DNS servers?
I should say that I just need a JSON file from that server, so It's just exhausting to change DNS servers every time.

Comment: Looks like it is the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609385/python-requests-library-define-specific-dns

Comment: actually, I think it's a different answer and doesn't work for me.