# Python Locust: how to use different DNS server?

Tags: python, locust

I need locust to use a different DNS server - when resolving the URL? Is this possible?

```
class User(HttpUser):
    @task
    def get_data(self):
        headers = {'authToken': self.token,
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

        res = self.client.get("/data", headers=headers, dns=8.8.8.8)
```

that dns = 8.8.8.8 doesn't exist but its the functionality I'd like.

nslookup has this functionality: `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Applications don't generally control how name resolution is done, this is a system configuration setting.

Comment: Why would you want to override the user's DNS settings? This is a horrible UX that many pro users have complained about extensively in the past when used (inadvertently or otherwise) to bypass things like Pi-Hole/etc. This will also break your code unnecessarily on higher-security networks where outbound DNS is filtered to specific addresses.

Comment: "Why would you want to override the user's DNS settings? " I can think of a few reasons. users who are in different regions will get different DNS servers.

Answer (score 1):

[The Locust client inherits from Requests](https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#control-headers-or-other-things-about-my-http-requests). Something like the answers to this question should work.

[Python 'requests' library - define specific DNS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609385/python-requests-library-define-specific-dns)