# DNS_SERVERS on pycurl

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to use pycurl to download test page using different resolvers.

```
>>> pycurl.version
'PycURL/7.19.3.1 libcurl/7.35.0 WinSSL'
```

I tried:

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.DNS_SERVERS, '1.2.3.4')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pycurl.error: (4, '')
```

It happens on Linux and Windows equally. What am I doing wrong?

Can I use different resolvers with urllib2?

Comment: This answer might help if you want to use urllib2 http://stackoverflow.com/a/2237040/21945

Answer (score 3):

From http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

Error 4

> CURLE_NOT_BUILT_IN (4)
>
> A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this
>   libcurl due to a build-time decision. This means that a feature or
>   option was not enabled or explicitly disabled when libcurl was built
>   and in order to get it to function you have to get a rebuilt libcurl.

My guess is that the underlying libcurl c library was not compiled with the c-ares library included.

To resolve this it may require compiling libcurl yourself and enabling c-ares in the configure script.

urllib2 might be an option see [Tell urllib2 to use custom DNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236498/tell-urllib2-to-use-custom-dns)