# PycURL send DNS traffic through particular interface

Tags: python, curl, networking, libcurl, pycurl

I have multiple interfaces on the box and want to force the traffic through a particular interface using python.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996494/send-http-request-through-specific-network-interface) answers how to do that for HTTP traffic. But when I look at tcpdump, the DNS queries do not honor the interface setting. libcurl provides options to force DNS traffic through a particular interface using option [CURLOPT_DNS_INTERFACE](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DNS_INTERFACE.html) and [CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4.html)

I tried using the same through C and it seems to honor the interface when libcurl is built with c-ares support.

But when the same options are used from the pycurl version result in the following errors:

```
AttributeError: DNS_INTERFACE
AttributeError: DNS_LOCAL_IP4
```

I am trying monkey patching suggested [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585317/requests-bind-to-an-ip). But based on the comments, other people already reported that it's not working. Thanks.

**[edit]** Tested the above-mentioned monkey-patching with bind, tcpdump still shows traffic through a different interface. Fixed formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AttributeError happens since PycURL only supports curl options that it lists in src/[module.c](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/blob/REL_7_43_0_2/src/module.c).  One can add support for CURLOPT_DNS_INTERFACE by mirroring how it supports CURLOPT_INTERFACE -- by adding

```
    insint_c(d, "DNS_INTERFACE", CURLOPT_DNS_INTERFACE);
```

and

```
    case CURLOPT_DNS_INTERFACE:
```

in src/module.c and src/easyopt.c after the lines about CURLOPT_INTERFACE, I could build a version that supports DNS_INTERFACE.  I used `python setup.py install` for the build (see [docs](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#distutils)), running into two errors that were solved with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24051044/1628638) and `make src/docstrings.c` (see [GitHub](https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/issues/198)).

Here the example from the [docs](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html) with DNS_INTERFACE added:

```
import pycurl
from StringIO import StringIO

buffer = StringIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://pycurl.io/')
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.setopt(c.DNS_INTERFACE, "enp9s0")
c.perform()
c.close()

body = buffer.getvalue()
print(body)
```

It currently gives me `pycurl.error: (4, '')` on the `c.setopt(c.DNS_INTERFACE, "enp9s0")`, but this error would [likely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24121481/1628638) not happen for you since you built libcurl with c-ares support.